# convert string to regex pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to find the pattern of a regular expression from a character string. My goal is to be able to reuse this pattern to find a string in another context but checking the pattern.

from sting `"1example4whatitry2do"`, 
I want to find pattern like: `[0-9]{1}[a-z]{7}[0-9]{1}[a-z]{8}[0-9]{1}[a-z]{2}`

So I can reuse this pattern to find this other example of sting `2eytmpxe8wsdtmdry1uo`

I can do a loop on each caracter, but I hope there is a fast way

Thanks for your help !

Comment: so you want to be able to generate a regex pattern from a single instance of what you're trying to match, then use that regex to search for additional matches?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: and it can be assumed the strings will only contain alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Yes, I'm cleanning text before (remove extra caracters) and convert to lowercase But if you have a solution to mange it :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specifically can we help you with?

Comment: I had tried to make loops but I didn't find the process very practical because in each case I had to specify the type of character I was looking for (alpha, numeric, special characters). Indeed, I should have specified all that, which is worth a -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can puzzle this out:

- go over your strings characterwise

  - if the character is a text character add a `'t'` to a list
  - if the character is a number add a `'d'` to a list
  - if the character is something else, add itself to the list

Use `itertools.groupby` to group consecutive identical letters into groups.
Create a pattern from the group-key and the length of the group using some string literal formatting.

Code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from string import ascii_lowercase

lower_case = set(ascii_lowercase) # set for faster lookup

def find_regex(p):
    cum = []
    for c in p:
        if c.isdigit():
            cum.append("d")
        elif c in lower_case:
            cum.append("t")
        else:
            cum.append(c)

    grp = groupby(cum) 
    return ''.join(f'\\{what}{{{how_many}}}' 
                   if how_many>1 else f'\\{what}' 
                   for what,how_many in ( (g[0],len(list(g[1]))) for g in grp))

pattern = "1example4...whatit.ry2do"

print(find_regex(pattern))
```

Output:

```
\d\t{7}\d\.{3}\t{6}\.\t{2}\d\t{2}
```

The [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) in the formatting removes not needed `{1}` from the pattern.

See:

- [str.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.ascii.html#curses.ascii.isdigit)

If you now replace `'\t'`with `'[a-z]'` your regex should fit. You could also replace *isdigit* check using a regex `r'\d'` or a `in set(string.digits)` instead.

```
pattern = "1example4...whatit.ry2do"

pat = find_regex(pattern).replace(r"\t","[a-z]")
print(pat) # \d[a-z]{7}\d\.{3}[a-z]{6}\.[a-z]{2}\d[a-z]{2}
```

See

- [string module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) for *ascii_lowercase* and *digits*

Comment: @Manu fixed some error - I somehow omitted the step of converting `'\t'` to a character range and I now use a set for character comparison what makes it faster. If it works, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work